# entity framework migration up table relationships incorrect?

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-migrations

Simple model to demonstrate three types of relationships:

One-To-One - Deed and House: House has 1 deed and 1 deed is for that house

One-To-Many - House -> Room: My House has many rooms

Many-To-Many - Room <-> Color: The Many rooms can have many of the same colors

The classes (without the constructors):

```
 public class Deed   {
     public int DeedId { get; set; }
     public string Owner { get; set; }
     public House Home { get; set; }

  public class House
  {
    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

  public class Room
  {
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    List<Color> Colors { get; set; }

  public class Color
  {
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
```

My confusion is in the Migration UP constructors:
First the one to one:  I get an error when Deed and House point to each other saying it cannot determine the "principle".  So I made Deed the principle:

[image: Deed 1-to-1 with Home]

Next House has Many Rooms.  I think I understand that the foreign key is ONLY in each room pointing back to the house like this:
[image]

Next is where I really get confused.  I would expect the Many ROOMS share Many COLORS (many to many)... each would point to the other. BUT:

[image]

I appreciate your advice.
Thanks in advance,
Yogi ("Chuck")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this minor cleanup of your model.  Also why wouldn't a House have multiple Deeds?  And anyway EF6 makes it hard to model 1-1 relationships.  You either have to make the DeedId the FK to House, or make Deed a Complex Type instead of an Entity.

```
public class Deed
{
    public int DeedId { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    public House House { get; set; }
}

public class House
{
    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; } = new HashSet<Room>();
}
public class Room
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    public House House { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Color> Colors { get; } = new HashSet<Color>();
}
public class Color
{
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; } = new HashSet<Room>();

}
 public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Deed> Deeds { get; set; }
    public DbSet<House> Houses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Color> Colors { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: David, you are absolutely right.  I think I understand now.  The Deed/House relationship is contrived just to get a 1-1 relationship.  I'm going to check it now, but if you might clarify the reason for "virtual" ??  Thanks.  Chuck

Comment: Virtual navigation properties enable Lazy Loading, where EF generates runtime subtypes that fetch related entities on demand.